# jQuery .keydown() no funciona en los campos que se añaden posteriormente

Tags: jquery, formularios

En mi aplicación web **se añaden inputs durante las interacciones de los usuarios**, y tengo un problema y es que el [.keydown()](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/) de jQuery no me funciona en estos inputs.

Sin embargo, sí funciona en los campos que ya vienen en la página cuando esta es cargada. Me gustaría saber si este es el problema o si tengo algo mal y una posible solución.

**Input donde sí funciona** (Cargado al inicio):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
```

**Input donde NO funciona** (cargado al pulsar en un botón con [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/)):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="url0" name="url0">
```

**Código** usado para detectar cuándo el usuario termina de escribir:

```
var timer = null;
$('input').keydown(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        alert('Ya está');
    }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: Es por que el evento tienes que volver a asignarlo, ya que el elemento nuevo no estaba en el dom inicialmente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con el metodo `on()` puedes ligar eventos a elementos creados dinamicamente. Si lo intentas de esta forma debería funcionar:

```
var timer = null;
$(document).on('keydown', "input",function () {  
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        alert('Ya está');
    }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: Aquí más información: http://api.jquery.com/on/ Y en esta otra pregunta también explica cómo el evento `on` pueden procesar eventos de elementos añadidos dinámicamente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements